# How to list all changes in settings to TeamCity server?

Tags: unit-testing, teamcity-8.0

During a course of a number of days I'm running test each third hour. All has been passing with flying green colors. Then, suddenly, a failure occurred. I've checked the checkins and there's nothing new checked in (except changes to a BAT file when some comments were removed). Now the tests pass **exactly** every second time. And when they fail (**precisely** every other second time, it's always due to the same three test methods).

The said change can't possibly cause the tests to fail because it's only *echo* line being removed, the file itself is not run during build/test, it's not even being copied prior the installation and, to make it super-duper-extra sure, the changes to it's been retracted.

So, there are only two possible explanations left:

1. It's due to magic, the very bad kind.
2. Something changed to the settings on the server.

I'll post a corresponding question at Stack Exchange Sorcery but for now, let's focus on the second item - the changes to the settings on the server.   :)

When I click around I can see who's made the last change and when. I can also obtain a historics of the former changes. Most importantly - I can see **what** has been changed. However, this approach implies going through all the build steps, configurations, repositories etc. It's not a feasible nor sane way to do this, let alone I'm bound to forget or miss some obscure setting (and given Murphy's Law, that'll be the exact spot when the dead dog lies buried).

Question:
Is it possible to list all the changes from all the settings in one, comprehensive table, including, but not necessarily limited to, the profile that made the change, the occasion of the change and the contents of the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all users actions into the [Audit log](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Tracking+User+Actions), which is available at the Administration -> Audit page.